# How can draw the bezier curve in excel or on graph?

Tags: math, curve

I'm trying to implement beizer curve like Gimp curve at excel.

I used the function which is `(1-x)^2 p0 + 2x(1-x)p1 +x^2 p2`.

X is from 0 to 1. P0 is 0 and p2 is 1 and I controlled p1 from 0~1.

But the result was not matching as my expectation. 
Does anyone know how to draw the beizer curve at excel or on graph?
[Link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxh0ejjcox)

Comment: Check out [page 25 on this Iowa State Paper](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/dept/thesisarchive/MSCC/HarwoodMSMS09.pdf)

Comment: @JGreenwell I have one more question. How can I add one more point on 4 point equation?

Comment: if you have a question like this again you might get better answers on [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Just look at how point D was added on that paper and repeat for point E - if that doesn't work update your question with your code and the problem your having and we can help from there

Comment: @JGreenwell I got it.